# I don't get the website's up-to-date html

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching

I changed the .htaccess file to cache everything for a year.
After a while, I noticed that I don't see the updates I make to the website.

I figured out, that because I changed the default cache to a year, somehow the html file got cached for 1 year, and even though I've changed it back, still doesn't work.

The only way I could make it update is to use different links (like www.domain.com/newlink insead of www.domain.com/oldlink), but that doesn't repair my frontpage, as it is www.domain.com, and I can't change that.

Do you have any solution for my problem?

P.S. It isn't my browsers cache, as I have cleared it's cache, I even reinstalled it, and if that's not enough, I can't see the updated version on my phone.

P.P.S. I can see that the http request doesn't even reach the server for the www.domain.com link.

P.P.P.S. I tried using a proxy, and the page worked as it should, so I think it's only cached at my ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to explicit say not to cache to apache in the htaccess. Also restarting your apache server might work.

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: You are a genious! It worked instantly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Okay, so for some reason it's not working again. I don't know why, haven't changed anything.